# Error while loading xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Am dynamically loading an xml file and sending request to the api but getting 
`Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /home/spotrech/public_html/` but this error is  very inconsistent sometime appear sometime don't! I really no idea how to solve this. below is code

```
$rechargeApiUrl = "http://allrechargeapi.com/apirecharge.ashx?uid=$uid&apikey=$apike&number=$mobileNo&opcode=$opId&amount=$amount&ukey=$uniId&format=xml";
$url = file_get_contents($rechargeApiUrl);
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML(preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $url));
$itemInfo = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Result'); //returns an object.
$itemCount = $itemInfo->length;
foreach ($itemInfo as $userInfo) {
    //Assigning node values to its specified  variables.
    $ukey = strtolower($userInfo->getElementsByTagName('ukey')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $status = $userInfo->getElementsByTagName('status')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $resultCode = $userInfo->getElementsByTagName('resultcode')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$strStatus = strtolower(trim($status));
$strResultCode = trim($resultCode);
$strCode = trim($ukey);
```

any response will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: as it complains about an empty string it is quite likely the used api is not always returning what it should. try adding a check like `if($url === '') echo 'ow noes, dis not bein good'`

Comment: Why even preg_replace inside `loadXML()`? o_O Anyway, problem is simple. Empty string means that your preg_replace focked up everything (less likely). Or file was empty (more likely).

Comment: Maybe sometimes `http://allrechatgeapi.com` is down and you get no XML from it?